# jQuery .click(handler) finds input element blank in Greasemonkey script (addEventListener works, however)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, greasemonkey

I have a Greasemonkey script that does some associating between JIRA and a ticket app.  When you associate an item to a JIRA ticket, it makes some API posts to JIRA to add the other ticket to the JIRA so it's bidirectional.  The relevant HTML (which I don't have control to change) is:

```
<div id="related_inputs" class="related-items-actions-inner">
    <label class="align" style="width: 104px;">full_jira_url: </label>
    <input type="text" style="margin-left: 109px;">
    <br>
</div>
```

And the button:

```
<a id="relate-button" class="tt_button">
  <span id="relate-button-text">Relate</span>
</a>
```

So basically when a user clicks the button/link, I want to extract the value input in the input above (in the "related inputs" div) and then do some other stuff.  It used to work and is not any longer so I'm not sure if it is due to a browser regression, a JIRA change or a change to the website code I'm writing the script for.

The gist of the Greasemonkey script is:

```
(function () {
  console.log("Started script!");

  $('#relate-button').click( function(event) {

    var related_ticket_type = $('#related_inputs label').text().trim();
    console.log("ticket type is " + related_ticket_type);
    if (related_ticket_type != JIRA_LABEL_TEXT) { 
      return;
    }

    var jira_url = $('#related_inputs input').val();
    console.log(jira_url);  // <<== this is "" all the time now even when the input has data in it when pressed
    
    var match = jira_url.match(JIRA_REGEX);

    if (match.length != 2) {
      console.log("We didn't match the URL to a valid RDS Jira url.")
      return;
    }
    ...
```

The issue is that the value I'm getting from the input element is empty every time.  I've confirmed in the console that it is the correct input element.  The label element is correct two since it is getting to the input code.

Any ideas or suggestions?

After what I discovered below, the question comes down to: what is the difference between jQuery's `.click(handler)` vs `element.addEventListener( 'click', function(event) {...}, true)` ?

Comment: What version of Greasemonkey?  GM 2 FUBAR'd a few things.  What is your metadata block?  (link to the whole script as well, is best)  console log `$('#related_inputs input')` and triple-check that it is the expected node.

Comment: Yes, definitely the right node is found, it's just that due to some syncing issue, the value="" even if the text input has text in it at the time of clicking the link.  addEventListener solved it, though I don't know why.

Comment: Arggh, so I used .on('click'... and a delegate to attach the event to the outer div just incase the website was doing some AJAX but it still is finding that the text input field is blank (the label is always correct and there is only one input in the div so the input object is correct, just with a blank value="").  Any other ideas?

Answer (score -1):

So instead of using jquery's .click(handler), I did the following:

```
var button_el = document.getElementById('relate-button');

button_el.addEventListener( 'click', function(event) {....}, true);
```

Doing this fixed the issue (ie the value of the url was *not* blank).  However, I'd be really interested in knowing why this fixed my issue.

I'm using Greasemonkey 1.15.